# ¿Cómo puedo autocompletar datos en un input y aplicarlo en otros inputs?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap

> Trato de autocompletar datos en un input, pero no puedo aplicar la función en varios inputs. [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp), encontré esta porción de código, pero el problema está en que no se puede aplicar a varios inputs.

Comment: si lo que estas tratando de hacer es que varios inputs reflejen lo mismo que uno solo, no hace falta usar funciones, con un simple handle de un solo input y una variable global es posible y sencillo

Comment: Pero eso es lo que no quiero, trato de que sean independientes.

Comment: eso seria escribir el mismo codigo varias veces y no esta muy bien visto que digamos

Comment: Yo lo hice de esa manera para agregar campos y quitarlos al darle clic en un botón, pero al final los selects que se añadían me traían los datos que seleccionaba en el primer select y eso es lo que no quiero, usar una variable global me genera eso.

Comment: En w3school está todo el código completo, el enlace lo adjunté, esta variable contiene los elementos quemados, por decirlo así, var countries = ["Afghanistan"];

autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), countries); y este autocomplete me permite ejecutarlo cuando lo instancie en el id del button.

Comment: puedes usar el atributo name para tener mas manejo de esos inputs en el handle y aun asi seguir usando la variable global para no tener que escribir tanto codigo

Comment: Soy nuevo en Javascript

Comment: Lo que quiero es poder llamar la función en el button, para poder aplicarla a otros. Y no usar un Id predefinido.

Comment: Sí puedes usarlo para varios inputs: `autocomplete(document.getElementById("id-input1"), fuenteDeDatos1); autocomplete(document.getElementById("id-input2"), fuenteDeDatos2);`

Comment: @JonathanCastrillón no entiendo, solo quieres que tenga un autocompletado en el input y ese autocompletado se utilize en todos los inputs que quieras?

Comment: @JuanRivera exacto, la cuestión es que yo genero inputs dinámicamente y esos inputs los uso para buscar productos, quería saber si hay alguna forma de poder aplicar un autocompletado a N cantidades de inputs que yo genere dinámicamente.

Comment: @Triby la cuestión es que tendría que replicar ese código muchas veces y eso sería un problema en memoria, si es una solución, pero no me sirve en mi caso.

Comment: @JonathanCastrillón probastes utilizar [datalist](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp)? Porque con eso no es necesario hacer funciones, solo es HTML

Comment: @JuanRivera La verdad no he usado datalist, voy a consultar. Gracias amigo. Voy a implementarlo a ver como funciona :)

Comment: @JonathanCastrillón ok, lo pondre como respuesta dando un ejemplo simple

Comment: @JuanRivera lo acabé de implementar y me parece perfecto, muchas gracias. Dale colócalo como respuesta.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Una forma sencilla de hacer un `autocompletado` en un `input` es usar [datalist](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp), que basicamente es como un select pero para un input, un ejemplo simple seria lo siguiente:

```js
$( "#btn_add" ).click(function() {
  $('#inputs').append('<input type="text" list="productos"><br>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<datalist id="productos">
  <option value="Leche">
  <option value="Atun">
  <option value="Fideos">
  <option value="Arroz">
  <option value="Jugos">
</datalist>

<button id="btn_add">Agregar Input</button><br><br>
<div id="inputs"></div>
```